# Log return of two different timeseries

Tags: logarithms

Lets say I have a single timeseries, the simple return would be T/T<sub>-1</sub>-1

the log return would be ln(T/T<sub>-1</sub>)

But let's say I have two different time series, T and R

The values are close, but still differ slightly. I normally create an adjusted time series by doing the simple return calculation as follows

(T-T<sub>-1</sub>)/R<sub>-1</sub>

How can I convert this simple timeseries into a log return?